# Oracle update statement - how do you link to related tables?

Tags: oracle

I'm relatively new to Oracle, having working on MS SQL for most of my career.  I'm used to doing stuff like:

```
update t
set Col1 = o.Col2
from MyTable t 
join OtherTable o on t.OtherID = o.ID
```

I tried this syntax in Oracle, and it doesn't accept it.  Looked in [Oracle docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10007.htm#i2067715) and couldn't find an example of what I'm trying to do.

How do you do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option A)  A correlated subquery

```
UPDATE MyTable t
  SET Col1 = (SELECT o.col2 FROM OtherTable o WHERE t.OtherID = o.ID)
```

This requires that the subquery return no more than 1 match for each row in the table being updated.  If it returns no match, the column will be updated with `NULL`, which may not be what you want.  You could add `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT o.col2 FROM OtherTable o WHERE t.OtherID = o.ID)` to cause the update to only occur where a match is found.

Option B)  Updating a join view

```
UPDATE (SELECT t.col1, o.col2 FROM MyTable t JOIN OtherTable o ON t.otherID = o.ID)
  SET col1 = col2
```

This is closer to what you are used to doing.  It will only work if Oracle can determine a unique row in the underlying table for each row in the join -- which I think basically means that `ID` must be a unique key of `otherTable`.

Answer (score 2):

```
update (select t.OtherID, t.Col1  , o.ID, o.Col2 from MyTable t 
join OtherTable o on t.OtherID = o.ID) a
set a.Col1 = a.Col2
```

Comment: And what if the columns in `o` and `t` have the same names?

Comment: yes, should never use * indeed.. i updated the query to name the fields specifically

Comment: That works only if the subquery is "key-preserved" - see Dave Costa's answer.

Comment: The implication of this syntax is that you can update multiple tables simultaneously - is that true?

Comment: As said in other comments, you can update multiple tables only if there are unique / primary key fields included in the view (this way Oracle knows which row to update)... Also you cannot obviously update those unique fields

Comment: @Shaul, no - there must be exactly 1 "key-preserved" table in the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
update MyTable t
set Col1 = (SELECT o.Col2 from OtherTable o
            WHERE t.OtherID = o.ID)
where exists (SELECT o.Col2 from OtherTable o
            WHERE t.OtherID = o.ID)
```

The "where exists" part is to prevent col1 being set to NULL for MyTable rows that don't have a match in OtherTable - assuming this could happen and needs to be prevented.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary table like so:

```
update
(
    select t.Col1, o.Col2
    from MyTable t
    join OtherTable o
        on t.OtherID = o.ID
) tmp
set tmp.Col1 = tmp.Col2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update MyTable t
set Col1 = (SELECT o.Col2 from OtherTable o
            WHERE t.OtherID = o.ID)
```

Comment: Beware that this sets MyTable.Col1 to NULL if there is no match in OtherTable.